# Parsing XML for iPhone (aMule downloads/ search results)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser

I am currently working on a software to control aMule status of my server through the iPhone,
i created a socket that spits out xml which should be parsed out, but because NSXMLParser is event-drive, i'm having problems in understanding how this could work...
I thought of this type of XML structure, if you have ideas of a better way to structure it please tell me!! :D

```
<root type="donwloads">   <-- specifies downloads or search results
<file name="Ubuntu_9_10.iso" status="[11,6%]" />
<file name="Fedora 12.iso" status="[56,2%]" />
</root>
```

What i was thinking is, as i want to put this in a tableview, most probably i will need a NSMutableArray with lots of NSDictionaries based on the results, every dict should be a file.. what do you guys propose?? how should i handle this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answers :D fortunately i resolved the problem 10 minutes after :D
ill post what i did:

XML:

```
<root>
  <downloads>
<file type="text" name="fdsdf" />
<file type="text" name="sdfsdfssds" />
  </downloads>
</root>
```

NSXMLParser delegates:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName       namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"downloads"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"results"]){
    NSLog(@"starting or downloads or results");
    if(xmlArray){
        xmlArray= nil;
    }
    self.xmlArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"file"]){
    NSLog(@"found file...");
    [self.xmlArray addObject:attributeDict];
   }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"downloads"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"results"]){
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"downloads"]){
        NSLog(@"downloads found: %@...  reloading table", xmlArray);
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this can possibly help someone which has my same problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Write a parser class that turns nodes into Core Data managed objects and saves them to the managed object context, when a parser callback event is fired.

Use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to access the Core Data store. As the managed objects come in and are saved, the results controller updates the table view with whatever results it fetches.

Answer (score 1):

An `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionary` seems like a reasonable approach for your in-memory data structure.

You'll basically have a series of callbacks that build up that array as `NSXMLParser` runs through your XML file:

```
- (void) parseXML:(NSString *) filename {
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filename];

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];

    [xmlParser parse];

    // Check for errors.
    NSError *errorCode = [xmlParser parserError];
    if (errorCode) {
        // handle error here
        NSLog(@"%@", [errorCode localizedDescription]);
    }

    [xmlParser release];
}
```

And your main delegate:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    // If certain elements are found initialize the object
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:"@file"]) {
       NSMutableDictionary *currentFile = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
       // Look through the attributes add stuff to your dictionary
       // Add it to your array.
    }
}
```

Since all of your data is returned in attributes you can do it this way.  Otherwise you'd need to store the file and build it up (the `foundCharacters` delegate) finally adding it to your array when the file's tag occurs in the `didEndElement` delegate.

Comment: You'll also want to call `reloadData` on your `UITableView` after you finish the parse.